# Reactive Extensions OnNext thread-safety

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety, system.reactive

With the Rx `Subject`, is it thread-safe to call `OnNext()` from multiple threads?

So the sequence can be generated from multiple sources.

Will merge do the same thing?

Comment: very interesting question !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Rx contract requires that notifications be sequential, and is a logical necessity for several operators. That said, you can use the available `Synchronize` methods to get this behaviour.

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();
var syncedSubject = Subject.Synchronize(subject);
```

You can now make concurrent calls to `syncedSubject`.
For an observer which must be synchronized, you can also use:

```
var observer = Observer.Create<Unit>(...);
var syncedObserver = Observer.Synchronize(observer);
```

Test:

```
Func<int, Action> onNext = i => () => syncedSubject.OnNext(i);
Parallel.Invoke
(
    onNext(1),
    onNext(2),
    onNext(3),
    onNext(4)
);
```

Answer (score 7):

No, sequences are meant to be sequential, hence no overlapping notifications are allowed. You can use Synchronize extension methods to enforce proper synchronization. Operators like Merge take a lock to call the downstream observer in order to ensure proper serial invocation on On* callbacks.

Comment: It is possible to provide a example using the Synchronize extension method?

Answer (score 7):

Calling `someSubject.OnNext()` is as thread-safe as `someList.Add()` - you can call it from > 1 thread, but not concurrently. Wrap your `OnNext` in a `lock` statement and it'll be safe.