# Batch processor (aggregate items out of a queue)

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, locking

I have a `System.Timers.Timer` which elapses every *3 seconds*.
Once it elapses I want to take *all* the items in my collection and process them in one batch.

The motivation for that is to reduce the number of I/Os on the backend system.

The challenge is that I have multiple concurrent threads appending to the collection/queue. And because of this I thought about using a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` - but that's a bad choice.

This [article on social msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/accf4254-ee81-4059-9251-619bc6bbeadf/clear-a-concurrentqueue?forum=rx) describes the problem here very good.

**What I need is a collection/queue where I can get all data at once (ToArray()) and clearing the queue in one atomic operation so that I don't lose any data written to the collection/queue by other threads in the meantime.**

```
 private static void T1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
    string[] result = _queue.ToArray();
   _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(); // strings will be lost :-)
 }
```

I tend to use a simple lock-based approach on a simple `Queue<T>`.

```
 private static readonly object _myLock = new object();

 private static void T1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     string[] result;
     lock (_myLock)
     {
         result = _queue.ToArray();
         _queue.Clear();
     }
 }
```

Now this piece of code has one obvious flaw which can be seen in the producer code:

```
private static void ProduceItems()
{
    //while (!_stop)
    for(int i=0; i<int.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        if (_stop) break;

        lock (_myLock) // bad. locks out other producers running on other threads.
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enqueue " + i);
            _queue.Enqueue("string" + i);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000); // FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES ONLY
    }
}
```

**Of course this code will lock out any other producers trying to append to the queue.** Is there any way I can only validate the lock in the producers if the "T1_Elapsed" lock has been set?

Is there anything more suitable to my problem? Maybe anything Observable? Or are there any good "batcher/aggregator" examples?

**UPDATE 1: RX**
Awesome what you can do with RX :)
I'm still looking into how I can handle errors, retries or re-enqueues in this scenario.

```
internal class Rx
{
    internal static void Start()
    {
        ISubject<int> subject = new Subject<int>();
        ISubject<int> syncedSubject = Subject.Synchronize(subject); // that should do it? - UNTESTED!

        var subscription = syncedSubject.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10)
            .Subscribe((item) => ProcessBatch(item));

        for (int i=1; i<int.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            syncedSubject.OnNext(i);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.WriteLine($"Produced {i}.");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
        subscription.Dispose();
    }

    private static void ProcessBatch(IList<int> list)
    {
        // Aggregate many into one
        string joined = string.Join(" ", list);

        // Process one
        Console.WriteLine($"Wrote {joined} to remote storage.");

        // how do you account for errors here?
        myProducer.ReEnqueueMyFailedItems(list); // ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TPL DataFlow**

I'd say give the TPL DataFlow library a go. It is build upon the Task Paralled Library and designed for these kind of requirements where concurrency plays a big role. See http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html for a series of blog posts about this library.

The `BatchBlock` seems like a good fit for your scenario. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228602(v=vs.110).aspx for a tutorial.

Another example of using the `BatchBlock`:
https://taskmatics.com/blog/simplifying-producer-consumer-processing-with-tpl-dataflow-structures/

Instead of posting data to a queue you will post to one of the available TPL Dataflow blocks.

another option could be using

**Reactive Extensions**

See http://www.introtorx.com/uat/content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html for a good introduction

It provides batching support as well:

```
void Sample()
{
    var dataprovider = new Subject<int>();

    var subscription = dataprovider
        .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3))
        .Subscribe(listOfNumbers => 
        {
            // do something with batch of items
            var batchSize = listOfNumbers.Count;
        });

    for(int i = 0; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        dataprovider.OnNext(i);
    }

    subscription.Dispose();
}
```

In the above example, you need some modifications to enable multiple producers from different threads to add data, see [reactive extension OnNext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270642/reactive-extension-onnext). It is simplified code(!) but it gives you a general idea of the concept of using RX.

Buffering can be done using a max buffer size, a given timeperiod or a combination of both. So it can replace your timer as well.

Instead of adding items to a queue you call `OnNext` on the `Subject`

Both TPL DataFlow and RX eliminate the use of a queue or something alike that needs to be cleared, so it will free you from that pain.

Comment: I knew there was something out there ;-) I'm really impressed by the RX extensions. Your example really helped. Now I only need to figure out how any retry/fail mechanisms fit into this.

Comment: You could send them to another RX stream and handle them in that particular subscribe action. There are also build-in error handling strategies but it depends a little bit on what kind of action you need in case of failure.