# Observable mediator with Rx.NET

Tags: c#, rx.net

```
class SomeMediator
{
  public string[] Inputs { get; private set; }
  public ISubject<string> Response { get; private set; }
  
  public SomeMediator(string[] inputs)
  {
    Inputs = inputs;
    Response = new Subject<string>();
  }
}

class SomeProcessor
{
  public SomeProcessor(SomeMediator mediator)
  {
    foreach (var input in mediator.Inputs) 
    {
      var clock = new Timer();
      
      clock.Interval = 1000;
      clock.Enabled = true;
      clock.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(
        (object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) => 
          mediator.Response.OnNext(string.Empty));
    }
  }
}

class SomeRenderer 
{
  public SomeRenderer(SomeMediator mediator)
  {
    mediator.Subscribe(o => Console.WriteLine(o));
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var mediator = new SomeMediator(new[] { "Input#1", "Input#2" });
var subscriber = SomeRenderer(mediator);
var processor = SomeProcessor(mediator);
```

The code above injects `SomeMediator` with 2 input parameters into `SomeProcessor` and subscribes `SomeRenderer` to all responses.
Based on 2 inputs, `SomeProcessor` creates 2 `Timer` threads and starts sending notifications to `SomeMediator`.
Each `Timer` asynchronously calls `SomeMediator.Response.OnNext` and I'm getting a warning below

```
Warning: 0 : OnNext called while another OnNext call was in progress on the same Observer
```

As a result, the second `OnNext` message gets lost, so `SomeMediator` receives only 1 response from `SomeProcessor` instead of 2.

**The question**

Is it possible to implement mediator interaction through observable and prevent `OnNext` conflicts caused by different threads?

**Update - Example**

Let's say, there is a stock trading app that has some abstract generic `Core` functionality that can be reused by other apps. This core can include some market data formatter (mediator) to turn API response of various formats into a unified model (response) and visualize it (renderer). The response is supposed to be received from different gateways (processors) that will have specific implementation and will depend on the API provided by the brokerage firm.

In other words, we have multiple processors, like `SomeProcessor1`, `SomeProcessor2`, `SomeProcessor3` that will act as API wrappers. They accept some input parameters for the HTTP request (inputs) and return a response. Inputs are used by API processors. Mediator only gets the result and sends it to the visualizer. Mediator has `Subject` that is passed to each `Processor` and allows `Renderer` to subscribe to these changes. Every time some processor sends an update, the renderer should receive this notification through the mediator and show it in UI.

```
Processor1      Processor2     Processor3        (API)
            \       |        /
                 Mediator                        (Aggregate and Format)
               /         \
         Logger           Renderer               (Subscribed tasks - Log and Display)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you want to do with the mediator? Why do you not use the `ToObservable()` method to create an observable from the list you have?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270642/reactive-extensions-onnext-thread-safety

Comment: @Progman I could use Observable instead of Subject, but it doesn't fix the issue - missing messaging from async threads. There is no list to create an observable from. Response is supposed to be received by `Processor` first, and then handled by `Renderer`. Mediator only defines the way they interact with each other.

Comment: @Ehssan  Yes. I think this explains the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Anonymous "There is no list to create an observable from", but `SomeMediator.Inputs` is a list. In fact the `ToObservable()` method can be used on any `IEnumerable`. Can you [edit] your question to include an example with a bigger input vector and write exactly which value should be emitted by which subject/observable which is consumed where and when?

Comment: @Progman  Updated. Although, after reading other answers from the link in the comment, it seems that events suit better for async updates than observables...